# Can a non-indian spouse claim rights/share in Indian properties on divorce?

Tags: united-states, immigration, india, divorce

I am a divorced Indian citizen in USA and have grown up kids in India. I am going to get married to a non-Indian citizen in USA. She has German citizenship and will still have her German citizenship after our marriage. We plan to register the marriage in USA and Germany too. But, we haven't planned to register it in India or Indian consulate yet. I have some real estate and other financial establishments in India. In case of divorce, can she claim her rights in the establishments which are in India? I want to protect those properties and establishments for my children in India. Will a prenup made in USA between an Indian and non-Indian recognized in India? Can it be enforced it in India?

Answer (score 1):

She is not Indian citizen. You are registering marriage in USA & Germany. You are not Indian resident. So It depends on Alimony provisions of USA & Germany.
If you want to protect your properties for your children in India, Transfer your properties to your children. If you want to have control over properties, Transfer the ownership but get appointed as trustee of those properties until they get adulthood or married.